# ZFC + Grothendieck universes vs Mac Lane's One universe

Tags: set-theory

First note that I'm not an expert in set theory, but do have an interest in the topic in that I want to be able, at least in principle, to reduce my mathematics to the underlying axioms of my chosen set theory.

In ["One universe as a foundation for category theory"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0059147), Saunders Mac Lane proposes that a somewhat good foundation for category theory can be obtained when adding to the [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) set theory the axiom that there exists at least one [Grothendieck universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) $U$ which contains the set of natural numbers. Let's call this theory ZFCU*.

The universe set $U$ forms a model of ZFC set theory, and the subsets of $U$ form a model on [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) set theory. Deviating from Mac Lane's terminology, I call a *set* an element of $U$, a *class* a subset of $U$, and a *collection* an arbitrary element of ZFCU*.

In my research, I have adopted the ZFCU* as my underlying theory, but my results still concern only ZFC. I use the extra powers ZFCU* to provide short notations, such as $\mathfrak{c}$ for the class of the connected spaces, and to formalize transfinite sequences, among other things.

Right now ZFCU* serves me quite well. But sometimes I wonder whether I should in fact adopt the stronger set theory of ZFCU, which is ZFC with the axiom that *each* set is contained in some universe, which I believe is also known as the [Tarski-Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory) set theory. It is also equivalent to ZFC and the [existence of strongly accessible cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal) of arbitrary size.

The way I'm imagining it is as follows. Instead of my sets-classes-collections hierarchy in ZFCU*, I would construct a nested increasing sequence of universes, starting from the set of natural numbers. I would number these nested universes with ordinals. Then I could say that the elements of the i:th universe are level-i sets. The level-0 sets would be those of ordinary ZFC. The level-1 sets would be those of ZFCU*. The level-i classes would be subsets of the i:th universe. This would provide me with a large hierarchy of sets which would quite probably suffice for all of my constructions, including many of those in category theory.

It all sounds good to me, and Mac Lane also mentions the possibility of this approach:

> The Grothendieck school has proposed a strengthening of the axioms of set theory by requiring the existtence of many universes (definition below), specifically that each set be a member of a universe (see Gabriel [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory) or Verdier [5]).

In the next sentence, Mac Lane states though:

> This leads to complications attendant upon change of universe.

It is this sentence which makes me doubt adopting ZFCU. What are these complications that Mac Lane is referring to? Can my handwavy level-construction be formalized, and does it even correspond to how ZFCU is used in practice, or is it a different construction?

Comment: One has to be careful with universal properties. To quote the abstract of Zhen Lin Low's paper _Universes for category theory_: "Unfortunately, as soon as one allows the possibility of changing U, one also has to face the fact that universal constructions such as limits or adjoints or Kan extensions could, in principle, depend on the parameter U. We will prove this is not the case for adjoints of accessible functors between locally presentable categories (and hence, limits and Kan extensions), making explicit the idea that "bounded" constructions do not depend on the choice of U."

Comment: Link to the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5227

Comment: @theHigherGeometer Thanks for the link. Are these problems because two universes can be unrelated as in neither is contained in the other? If so, do these problems go away if the universes are arranged into an increasing sequence? I'm imagining fixing that sequence in some unique way once and for all, in the same way Mac Lane fixes the one universe.

Comment: No, the problem is not about the relative nesting. A universal property is a statement about "all" cones, but if you are working relative to a universe, then going up a universe means that now there are more cones, and in principle the universal property might fail for some of the new ones. In practice things are ok, as long as one is using constructions that in essence only "see" a bounded amount of data.

Comment: When working with other nested categories $C\subset D$ it is generally well-understood that a limit (for example) in $C$ might not remain a limit of the same diagram when considered as a diagram in $D$. But when working with $U-Set$, one hopes that this is suitably foundational, and also not sensitive to the actual choice of $U$, so that if one passes to a larger universe, the objects defined by some universal property retain that universal property. Local presentability is your friend here.

Comment: To make it more concrete, I do topology. The spaces are on the usual ZFC/level-0-sets. I have a function which I show to be a functor from the category of spaces to a subcategory of spaces. To formalize that function I use ZFCU*. I then show that that functor is right adjoint. And indeed here the products in the subcategory differ from the product topology. At this level, if I'm just studying the usual spaces (as in ZFC), I'm not sure why I would "go up a universe". (cont..)

Comment: Is the "going up a universe" about extending topological spaces to level-1-sets on so on? And then, based on some principles, I would perhaps be able to recycle whatever theorems I already know from the usual level-0 spaces as theorems of level-i spaces? But sometimes that recycling fails, and this is what I have to be careful about?

Comment: These are questions that are best put in a new question, I think.